# FindStyleResource cant find floatanimation

Tags: delphi, styles, firemonkey-fm2

I am trying to turn off the continuous animation on a progress bar in firemonkey. But I cannot figure out how to find the animation object using FindStyleResource.

```
T := MyProgressBar.FindStyleResource('floatanimation');
if (T <> nil) and (T is TFloatAnimation) then
  TFloatAnimation(T).Loop := false;
```

In the above code T is always nil.
Any suggestion on were I am going wrong with this is greatly appreciated.

Martin

Comment: Why do you expect the control to have a style resource with that particular name and type? Do you have some way of browsing the style resources at run time?

Comment: Not at runtime but at designtime I can find the animation in the style for the progress control.